# Having issues with UILabel not updating like it should

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a simple app using Swift that tells you if the number you are entering is a prime number or not. I know the logic is correct, but when I run the app and enter a number and press the button my label is not updating like it should. Can someone help me?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {




    @IBOutlet weak var number: UITextField!



    @IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel!


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var numberInt = number.text.toInt()

        if numberInt != nil {

            var unwrappedNumber = numberInt!


            var isPrime = true

            if unwrappedNumber == 1 {

                isPrime = false

            }

            if unwrappedNumber != 2 &&  unwrappedNumber != 1 {

                for var i = 2; i < unwrappedNumber; i++ {


                    if unwrappedNumber % i == 0 {
                        isPrime = false

                    }
                }

            }

            if isPrime == true{

                results.text = "\(unwrappedNumber)Is Prime"
            }else {

                 results.text = "\(unwrappedNumber)Is not Prime"
            }




        }else {

            results.text = "Enter a number"
        }




    }








    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Check uilabel results linked in interface builder or not?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var results: UILabel! Check results label variable  wether you have connected interface builder. Other thing u can do print the label check wether it is nil or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your project is you are performing a wrong action at wrong place like in your StoryBoard you right Click on TextField you find that you connected **Editing Did End** is connected with `@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject)` this action. because of this your action is not working.

Now the solution for your problem is remove your action connection from that textField by Clicking that cross button and it will look like :

[image]

after that connect ** buttonPressed** action with `Run Test` Button like this:

[image]

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Check-For-Prime-Numbers) I updated your code.

I recommended you to watch some tutorial on `UI` so you can batter understands how this all things works.

Comment: That is the way I did it. I copied your code into Xcode and its still not working for me. In fact with your code when I quite the simulator the debug   window opened up.

Comment: I did look at your project and I copied your code into Xcode. How do I share my project with you? I uploaded to GitHub but I don't think its done correctly.

Comment: My Github name is Dreunlimited and the project is called IsItPrime

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwr7jNszqaiAfm43bE4yNnlKdkNjVkZ0eEQwaTN6WEhzc2UwdlY1VWdON1RlRGVXM1ROams&usp=sharing

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you are trying to explain to me. I'm sorry but I am new to Swift and IOS programming in general.

Comment: Alright thank you, its working now. In simple terms could you explain what I did wrong so next time I know what to look out for?

Comment: It will be easy for you to understand if you do some tutorial on IBOutlet and IBActions in xcode.. :)